# ASP.NET MVC 4 Cache Manifest Extra Space Causing Parse Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cache-manifest

I'm having a strange issue working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Cache Manifest.

I've created a simple test solution here: http://andrewherrick.com/assets/MVC4EFOfflineCacheManifest.zip

You can see that something is adding an extra space at the top of the Cache Manifest file which is causing it to not parse. Any Idea what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}`

Make sure you remove the extra space after closing brace in _ViewStart